# Restrict Google Cloud Console to IP address range

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I need to restrict GCP console access to a specific IP address range, been doing some research online and it seems like I have to use Access Context Manager, however I can figure out how to link that access context to users and groups.
Any idea how to do that or if that's really the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Restricting Google Cloud Console to IP address range is possible using [BeyondCorp Enterprise](https://cloud.google.com/beyondcorp-enterprise/docs/securing-console-and-apis) it ensure the individuals and groups within your organization satisfying the defined access requirements are able to access the Google Cloud Console.

Steps to set up this feature:

1. [Optional] Deploy Endpoint Verification to devices in your organization.
2. Create an access level in Access Context Manager.
3. Create a group of users to be bound by BeyondCorp Enterprise restrictions.
4. Obtain the required Identity and Access Management permissions.
5. Create an access binding that enforces context-aware rules for the Google Cloud console and the Google Cloud APIs.

Here's also a step on [Creating an access binding](https://cloud.google.com/beyondcorp-enterprise/docs/securing-console-and-apis#creating_an_access_binding) to map between group of users created and the Access Context Manager access level you defined for accessing the Google Cloud console.

1. Go to the **BeyondCorp Enterprise** page in the Google Cloud console.
2. Choose an organization and click **Select**.
3. Click **Manage access** to choose which user groups should have access.
4. Click **Add** and configure the following:

- **Member groups**: Specify the group you want to grant access. Only groups not already bound to an access level are available to be selected.
- **Select access levels**: Choose the access level that should be applied to the group.

5. Click **Save**.

Alternatively you can also use the [VPC Service Controls](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/overview) to create perimeters that protect the resources and data of services.